# inequality of series, showing their difference is less than a number given it is monotonically increasing

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality

Given $a_1=1$ $$a_{n+1} =
\frac{2+2a_n}{2+a_n}  \text{is  bounded: } 1\leq a_n \leq 2, \quad  a_{n+1}-a_n=\frac{2(a_n-a_{n-1})}{(2+a_n)(2+a_{n-1})}$$

Prove $$|a_{n+1}-a_n|\leq \frac{1}3\left(\frac{2}9\right)^{n-1}$$

So I can show that $$\lvert a_{n+1}-a_n \rvert \leq \frac{2\lvert a_n-a_{n-1}\rvert }9,$$ but I then end up with $2/9\ldots$

Any hints? How should I be thinking of this? Like where does the $^{n-1}$ come from?

Comment: What is $a_0$? What have you done so far?

Comment: Sorry, $a_1=1$ I've edited. And well, the maximum difference between $a_n and a_{n-1}$ is going to be 1, which leaves me with $\frac{2}9$ but I understand that this difference will never be that large and that the difference should decrease as $n$ increases. I don't see, however, anyway I can increase the accuracy of my $\frac{2}9$

Comment: Have you proved that $$\lvert a_{n+1}-a_n \rvert \leq \frac{2\lvert a_n-a_{n-1}\rvert }9,$$ ?

Comment: Yes, I've got that far

Comment: Is my answer satisfactory or do you want more info?

Comment: So from what you've shown me, I do;
$b_n \leq \frac{2b_{n-1}}9$ then prove true for $n=1$ and assume true for $k$ where $b_n \leq \frac{2b_{n-1}}9$ and $b_{n+1} \leq \frac{2b_{n}}9$ I then sub in $b_k$ and get $(\frac{2}9)^2b_{k-1}$ I get how $b_1=1/3$ But dont see how to move on from here. I see I'm very nearly there, but don't get how to show the equation from what I have.

Comment: Is my edit any clearer?

Comment: Ahhh, yeah, I can get my head around it all now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have done most of the work already. Let $b_n=|a_{n+1}-a_n|$ for $n\in \mathbb{N} ^*$.

Then, you proved that $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}^*, b_n\leqslant \frac{2} {9} b_{n-1}$. You can prove $b_n \leqslant b_1 \left( \frac{2} {9} \right)^{n-1}$ using induction since $b_n$ is always positive.

**Goal:**
Prove that, $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}^*, b_n \leqslant b_1\left( \frac{2}{9} \right)^{n-1}$

**Initialization:**
At $n=1$, $b_1 = b_1 \times \left( \frac{2}{9} \right)^{1-1}$. Thus the property is initialized

**Heredity:**
If $b_{n-1} \leqslant b_1\left( \frac{2}{9} \right)^{n-2}$, then, since $b_n\leqslant \frac{2}{9} b_{n-1}$ then, $b_n \leqslant \frac{2}{9} \times b_1\left( \frac{2}{9} \right)^{n-2}=b_1\left( \frac{2}{9} \right)^{n-1}$

We thus proved the result for all $n>0$

As you noticed, $b_1=\frac{1}{3}$ hence the final result.

That is pretty much the proof for the general term of a geometric sequence.